# Bootstrap grid images issue

Tags: html, css

I have this basic blog setup where I display posts as a grid. The problem is, when I have 3 posts everything is looking good but when I enter another one and the line has to break to another row there is this strange collapse or something where the height of the first image it's not the same as the other ones. If I enter another one, the size problem happens to another image. Here's a photo:

[image]

The html I used(it contains php as I'm displaying posts from db) :

```
echo '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 postCol">';
    echo '<li class="list">';
    echo '<h1 class="titles"><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">'.$row['postTitle'].'</a></h1>';
    echo '<p>Posted on '.date('jS M Y', strtotime($row['postDate'])).' by '.'<span class="author-name">'.$row1['username'].'</span>'.'</p>';
    echo '<p>'.$row['postDesc'].'</p>';
    echo '<div class="imgT">';
        echo '<img class="img-responsive" src="'.$row2['imgLoc'].'"'.'/>';
    echo '</div>';         
    echo '<div class="read-more"><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">Read More >></a></div>'; 
    echo '</li>';
echo '</div>';
```

I'm using this css to style the images:

```
.imgT {
    margin: 0;
}


.imgT img{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
@media all and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .postCol:nth-child(2):after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .postCol:nth-child(3):after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
}
```

*(code is untestet)*

This piece of code simply adds bootstraps clearfix after every third child in desktop view. Your float should reset and kind of start a new row. You just need to adapt this to all your breakpoints.

**Note:** `li` nested in something else than `ol` & `ul` is invalid HTML, you should fix that.